# fetching waveform for visualization in c on any music files format (mp3/ogg/etc..)

Tags: c, visualization, waveform

I would like to know how can i fetch the a waveform from any music file format in order to visualize it using some kind of gui. i would like to use already written libraries instead of writing my own.

any ideas?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And for a library to do what you ask, check out [libsndfile](http://www.mega-nerd.com/libsndfile/).

Comment: libsndfile supports a lot of formats and it's very easy to understand. :) just like reading regular files from hard drive. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

That depends on the music file format.  [LameLib](http://www.spaghetticode.org/lame/) can be used for decoding mp3s, and [libogg](http://www.xiph.org/ogg/) can be used for decoding oggs.  Uncompressed wav files don't need to be decoded, since the file stores the raw PCM data; you just need to read in the file headers, and there's lots of sample code out there that shows you how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

If a program that lets you visualize an audio waveform would help, try Audacity.